# Passing client certificate on to another micro service in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, security, certificate

I have a micro service, `M1`, that requires a client certificate. When a request comes in via HTTPS I recive the `X509Certificate2` in the `HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate` property. The micro service carries out authentication based on this certificate.

`M1` then needs to call another micro service, `M2` and the call needs to be made using the client certificate passed to `M1` so that `M2` treats the call as coming from the same user. I've created a `HttpClient` in `M1` and attach the certificate to it via a `HttpClientHandler`. However, when I make the call into `M2` it fails with the error `The decryption operation failed`.

I'm no expert on security but I'm guessing this is something to do with the public/private keys used to decrypt the certificate? Is it valid to have a micro service use a client certificate it has received to try and authenticate with another micro service, and if so then how do I go about using the certificate in `M1` to authenticate with `M2`.

Comment: You never want to send the private key (which is in the certificate) along with the message.  It is like giving a Bank Robber key to the safe.  The certificate has to be installed in both client and server before any message are sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried certificate forwarding? It is well described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-certificate-authentication-in-azure-web-apps)